# MySQL row_count() rows affected

Tags: mysql, rowcount, executenonquery

There is very little documentation on MySQL's row_count() function. Is this function specific to each stored procedure (i.e. will multiple instances of the same stored procedure executing at the same time return the correct result)? Is there any circumstances where you would want to avoid this function?

I am using MySQL's .NET Connector and ExecuteNonQuery does not correctly return rows affected on updates and deletes, so I am hoping row_count() can serve as an effective alternative.

Answer (score 2):

The ROW_COUNT() value is the same as the value from the mysql_affected_rows(),

so if you insert 3 rows into a table

> SELECT ROW_COUNT();

will return 3 as the result

similarly if you delete 2 rows

> SELECT ROW_COUNT();

will return 2 as the result.

not sure if it will work on multiple instances of the same stored procedure, but it will return the number of rows affected on deletes and updates

Comment: As far as i know it can be used safely with multiple instances.